# How to replace @click by addEventListener and make addEventListener so flexible as @click?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, vuejs2, addeventlistener

Chrome on Android does not allow to play music\video if there is no any user movements. I found a piece of Google's code which uses `addEventListener` which sees user's interactions and plays music\video.

For some reason, Chrome on Android does not allow to play track if `@click` is used. Because of debugging and reading lots of info, I found that Chrome starts playing for a moment, but then stops. It probably happens because Chrome thinks that `@click` is kind of auto-play that may show some adverts and does not have any relation to user's interaction because Chrome requires an explicit action by the user. If I start to use `addEventListener`, Chrome starts playing without any problems. It could be ok for me to use `addEventListener`, but:

1) I need somehow to pass `trackObj` from template to event listener's function;

2) There are could be hundreds of tracks, I do not know if it is ok to add listeners to all of them.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(trackObj, index) in tagObj.tracks" :key="trackObj.trackId">

    // What I currently have and it works on PC, but not on Anroid + Chrome
    <b-card @click="nextTrack({whatToDo: 'playTrackObj', trackObj: trackObj})"
      class="dragula-move w-100 pl-2" no-body>
      {{ index + 1 }}. {{ trackObj.trackTitle }}
    </b-card>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('header', [
        'nextTrack'
      ])
    },

    // This work on Android + Chrome
    mounted () {
      // let self = this

      // let allTracks = document.getElementsByClassName('card dragula-move w-100 pl-2')
      // for (let i = 0; i < allTracks.length; i++) {
      //   allTracks[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      //     self.nextTrack({whatToDo: 'playDefaultTrack'})
      //   })
      // }
    }

  }
</script>
```

If I remove `@click="nextTrack(...)` from `<b-card>` and uncomment the code in `mounted ()`, Chrome on Android starts to see user's interaction and starts track playing.

Is there any way how to help Chrome on Android to see user's clicks using +- my existing code (ie `@click="nextTrack(...)`) or can anyone show me how it is possible to pass to EventListener a `trackObj` from template which can be used by self.nextTrack(...) function?

`@click.native` does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a custom directive with those objects as arguments. See below:

```js
Vue.directive('next-track', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    var vm = vnode.context;
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      vm.nextTrack({whatToDo: binding.value.whatToDo})
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'hello!',
    trackObj: 'something'
  },
  methods: {
    nextTrack(arg) {
      console.log('nextTrack called with', JSON.stringify(arg))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-next-track="{whatToDo: 'playTrackObj', trackObj: trackObj}">
    playTrackObj
  </div>
  <br>
  <div v-next-track="{whatToDo: 'click uss!', trackObj: trackObj}">
    click us and check the console
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean solution. Could you tell me, is it ok to add `addEventListener` to lots of items (few hundreds, or even 1 thousand)? Does it have any impact on performance or any other disadvantages?

Comment: Just hooking the event listener is unlikely to give you problems, as they will execute when the event actually happens. If you are really worried, you could hook the event in a common parent, and find another way to pass each elements' arguments. Anyway, I'd continue with your current approach and only worry if it ever becomes a noticeable problem (which is unlikely to happen soon).